# Error on searching in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

I have the following method that i uses to search for fields in database

this method return data and work right on my laptop local machine but didn't work and return empty data when i upload the project on server.

Note: sqlserver on my local laptop 2008 but on server 2012

here is the method

```
        //this method for search
    protected void fillGridView(int followingID, string text)
    {

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select t.*,u.firstName,u.lastName,u2.firstName as afirstName,u2.lastName as alastName ,i.icon,ii.iconPath as taskIcon, iii.iconPath as seenIcon,f.fileName,f.fileID from tasks as t inner join users as u on u.userID=t.addedBy inner join users as u2 on u2.userID=t.attachTo inner join priorityIcons as i on t.priority=i.priorityID inner join icons as ii on t.status=ii.iconName inner join icons as iii on t.isNew=iii.iconName left join files as f on t.fileID=f.fileID where t.followingID=@followingID and t.description LIKE '%" + text + "%' or t.followingID=@followingID and t.title LIKE '%" + text + "%'");

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@followingID", followingID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connection;

        myCommand.Connection = con;
        con.Open();            

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        try
        {

            adapter.Fill(ds);

            tasksRepeater.DataSourceID = null;
            tasksRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            tasksRepeater.DataBind();
            tasksCounter();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DAO.exDao myEx = new DAO.exDao();
            myEx.insert(ex);
            Response.Redirect("./error.aspx");
            //success = false;
            //throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi have you checked. let us know still it doesn't work for you ?

Comment: still id doesn't work

Comment: check in your db what type of datatype this id having ?

Comment: it is varchar(50), because i use a GUI algorithm to generate all IDs except followingID

Comment: pass this id from here as a string and please provide the error if still it is having(give the error details which is coming in catch)

Comment: followingID is int datatype in db, and there is no exceptions , but on my local laptop this method work fine and return right data, but on server this method didn't file exception, but it return an empty sit data, so i think there is some differences between sql server 2008 and sql server 2012, sine my laptop sql server is 2008 but server"on hosing" SQL server is 2012

Comment: have you uploaded the same 2008 db(in your laptop) to 2012(server) ? Micosoft Concept : all previous versions will work in new versions but reverse is not true. So on your case... it should work

Comment: Yes. i have uploaded the same database, but i found another problem when i uploaded it, every primary key or auto incremental field become as a normal field and miss it attribute, so i log in to date base "that online" using sql server management studio and add the attributes again to fields... so i think there is some thing incompatible between sql server 2008 and sql server 2012!!!

Comment: i found new note.... when i search for English word or number it return right data, but when i try to search for Arabic word it return no data!!

Comment: I solved the problem and i added the solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi replace your code with this

no need to write  DBAccess db = new DBAccess();

```
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@followingID", followingID));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text", text));
```

and

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        adapter .Fill(ds);
```

Comment: pass this id from here as a string and please provide the error if still it is having(give the error details which is coming in catch)

Answer (score -1):

i solver the problem by adding N character before the word that i try to find

and this is good work method

```
//this method for search
    protected void fillGridView(int followingID, string text)
    {

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select t.*,u.firstName,u.lastName,u2.firstName as afirstName,u2.lastName as alastName ,i.icon,ii.iconPath as taskIcon, iii.iconPath as seenIcon,f.fileName,f.fileID from tasks as t inner join users as u on u.userID=t.addedBy inner join users as u2 on u2.userID=t.attachTo inner join priorityIcons as i on t.priority=i.priorityID inner join icons as ii on t.status=ii.iconName inner join icons as iii on t.isNew=iii.iconName left join files as f on t.fileID=f.fileID where t.followingID=@followingID and t.description LIKE N'%" + text + "%' or t.followingID=@followingID and t.title LIKE N'%" + text + "%'");

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@followingID", followingID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connection;

        myCommand.Connection = con;
        con.Open();            

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        try
        {

            adapter.Fill(ds);

            tasksRepeater.DataSourceID = null;
            tasksRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            tasksRepeater.DataBind();
            tasksCounter();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DAO.exDao myEx = new DAO.exDao();
            myEx.insert(ex);
            Response.Redirect("./error.aspx");
            //success = false;
            //throw ex;
        }
    }
```